# DotMap with a variable named from receives unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, f-string

The code below will not execute because the fstring error.
Is from a reserved word in dotmap ?

```
from dotmap import DotMap

oWithFrom = {"from":"from Data", "to":"to Data"}

dmWithFrom = DotMap(oWithFrom)

print(f"to:{dmWithFrom.to}")

print(f"from:{dmWithFrom['from']}")

# This does not get past pylint
# invalid syntax (<fstring>, line 1)
print(f"from:{dmWithFrom.from}")
```

Comment: "from" is a reserved word in Python.  You can't have a variable or object member named "from".  Same with the other reserved words, like `if`, `else`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. rookie move. from is a keyword so it is getting parsed differently even as a dotmap variable.

Comment: Right.  DotMap is a facade.  It doesn't actually store those names as class members.  They're stored as a dict, so it's only when you try to refer to it as `x.from` that you trigger Python's anger.